# How to scaffold SQL synonym using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have to use a synonym from external database in my application. Is it possible to scaffold a synonym using Entity Framework Core in database first approach? I've tried to pass a synonym name to -Tables switch while trying to scaffold, but an output in console told me "Unable to find a table in the database matching the selected table MY_SYNONYM." How to work with synonyms using EF Core?

Comment: I am surprised you didn't get any answer.  Did you figure it out?

Comment: @JohnnyWu Thanks for your interest. If i remember correctly, back to these days, there was no possibility to scaffold a synonym (but i'm not 100% sure.). It seems that there is still no support for such a functionality in newer versions of our ORM. Regards

Answer (score 1):

In our circumstance we have replicated tables (using synonyms) to another DB from our ERP to lighten the load on the ERP for extra things like reporting.  So I scaffolded the classes from the ERP itself and then pointed the context to the DB with the synonyms.

But to your question, 2 years later EF Core still does not appear support synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

The hacky workaround we are using is to create a view that references the synonym and then scaffold and use the view.

It is ugly but it is working